# Catel together with Docking systems for example (Avalon Docking)

Tags: c#, mvvm, avalondock, catel

I'm looking for examples of using Catel together with Docking systems for example (Avalon Docking). Unfortunately in examples on GITHub is empty also there is nothing in the Orchestra. I would like to know how to use Docking together with Catel?

Answer (score 0):

We are planning to add this to Orchestra, but we didn't need it so far. But you can easily use the Fluent ribbon shell and put in the docking container as main view.

From there on it is just Catel as regular.

Comment: For example I want to create this window. http://images.cnitblog.com/blog/434268/201301/29200208-82cfe64c2a8347c7af59997600013e62.png  In the classic MVVM I created a few ViewModel set coordinates and size and put it in the collection and next set this collection in docingmanager but in Catel I can’t create view model manually.

Comment: You can (using the IViewModelFactory). However, such things can easily be handled by behaviors that you put on each view which makes your vm's much cleaner.